# Mongo vs MySql Search Optimization

Tags: mysql, mongodb, rdbms, nosql

So I'm in the process of designing a system that is going to store document type of data (i.e. transcribed documents).  Immediately, I thought this would be a great opportunity to leverage a NOSQL implementation like MongoDB.  However, given that I have zero experience with Mongo, I'm wondering:  on each of these docuemnts, I have a number of metadata tags I want to be able to search across:  things like date, author, keywords, etc.  If I were to use an RDBMS like MySql, I'd probably store these items in a separate table liked by a foreign key and the index the items that were most likely to be searched on.  Then I could run queries against that table and only pull back and the full text results for the items that matched (saves on disk read not having to reach through a row that contains a lot of text or BLOB information).

Would something similar be possible with Mongo?  I know in Mongo I could simply create 1 document that would have all the metadata AND the actual transcription but is it easy and highly performant to search the various fields in the metadata if the document is stored like that?  Is there a best practice when needing to perform searches across various items in a document in Mongo?  Or is this type of scenario more suited for an RDBMS rather than a NOSQL implementation?

Comment: Also to further clarify, im only concerned with reads.  Writes (inserts or updates) will be fairly minimal once the initial data load is completed.

Comment: Would paragraph separation hurt?

Answer (score 0):

You can add indexes for individual fields in mongodb documents. Only when the indexes get larger than your memory, performance of index based searches may become a problem.

When you decide if to go with mongodb, keep in mind that there is no join operation. This has to be done by your db layer or above.

If your primary concern is searching, there is an ElasticSearch river for mongodb, so you can utilize ElasticSearch on your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The NoSQL model, is geared for data storage in long range (OLTP model), yes you can create indexes and perform queries that you want, instead of you having related entities across tables, you have a complete entity that owns all entities dependent on it within herself.

When you have to extract complex reports with many joins in a relational database in a context of millions of data becomes impractical such an act, because you may end up compromising other applications.

For example:

We have the room and student bodies.

Each room have many students, the relational model we would have the following:

```
SELECT * FROM ROOM R
INNER JOIN
S STUDENT
ON = S.ID R.STUDENTID
```

Imagine doing that with some 20 tables with thousands of data? His performance will be horrible.

With MongoDB you will do so:

```
db.sala.find (null)
```

And will have all their rooms with their students.

MongoDB is a database that performs scanning horizontally.

You can read:

http://openmymind.net/mongodb.pdf

This site also has an interactive tutorial that uses the book's examples. Very nice.

And here you can experience the mongodb online and test your commands.

Search for try mongo db.

Also read about shards with replicaSets. I believe it will open your mind greatly.

You can install Robomongo which is a graphical interface for you to tinker with mongodb.

http://robomongo.org/